# Meteor cannot find path specified

Tags: meteor

Been trying to start meteor for a day now but no luck. This is what I get when I type meteor at the cmd prompt -

```
C:\Users\Chris&Vera>meteor
'Vera\AppData\Local\.meteor\' is not recognized as an internal or external 
 command, operable program or batch file.
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'meteor-promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at makeCompatible (C:\Users\Chris&Vera\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\tool-env\install-promise.js:6:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chris&Vera\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\tool-env\install-promise.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Please help.

Comment: Uninstall meteor and remove c:\Users\Chris&Vera\AppData\Local\.meteor folder. Then reinstall.

Comment: I would guess that it is related to the ampersand in your user directory. Those types of names generally pose a challenge when in executable path, and if anything in your dependency tree does not support them, your app will fail.